# Where is there a discussion of which decisions or laws will become invalid כאשר יבוא המשיח?

Tags: halacha-theory, messianic-redemption

Where is there a discussion about which laws/traditions/decisions will become invalid when the Messiah comes?

Why do the sages think that certain laws/or "mitzvoth" (if that helps in the search), or traditions /decisions will become invalid כאשר יבוא המשיח?

A similar (but different point) is made in this exchange, inclusive of information, as to which sages think likewise:
[When the Messiah comes, will the decisions/laws of Chazal still be in effect?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/when-the-messiah-comes-will-the-decisions-laws-of-chazal-still-be-in-effect)

Comment: Which sages say this. Remember to edit all relevant information into the question.

Comment: I don't think any Sages (at least, _our_ Sages) say that _any_ of the mitzvot will become invalid when Mashiach comes. That goes against basic Jewish belief to say such.

Comment: @ezra likewise, that is why that word is not included in the title, but only in the body (to serve as a synonym, in case it helps somebody in their search).

Comment: A similar (but different point) is made in this exchange, inclusive of information, as to which sages think likewise:
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/when-the-messiah-comes-will-the-decisions-laws-of-chazal-still-be-in-effect

Comment: @ezra would not the mitzva/mitzvoth about the coming of the messiah be, therefore, invalid after the messiah comes?

Comment: @ezra are not chagim in the mitzvot? Are there not discussions about abolition of the chagim when the messiah comes?

Comment: @ninamag - Where do you learn that the chagim will become abolished?

Comment: @ezra 'Our Sages teach that when the Messiah arrives the festivals will cease to be observed, but Purim will continue to be observed. The Midrash (Mishlei 9) derives this unusual conclusion from a statement in Megillat Esther, (9:28) “the memory of Purim will never cease from among their descendants.”'  (If you agree, please remove  your downvote.) https://www.ou.org/holidays/purim/purim_is_forever/

Comment: @ninamag - Does everyone accept that Midrash? (And I don't agree with you.)

Comment: @ezra which part you "don't agree with"? (Even if I myself don't agree with that Midrash, that is what that Midrash says.)

Answer (score 3):

There are many discussions of such issues so I will only refer to primary sources of Chazal. Regarding mitzvot/laws, see BT Nid. ([61b](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%90_%D7%91)) and PT ([Meg. 1:5](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%94)). The famous statement of the abolition of the Chagim, see Midrash Mishle [(ch. 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44204&st=&pgnum=57)).

With regards to [legal] decisions becoming invalid, this can possibly originate from the Lurianic school in which it is maintained that Halachah will be in accordance with Beit Shammai since the laws of that school are governed by "*din*" which is too fierce for this world that requires "*chesed*"; therefore it follows the school of Hillel which is overwhelmingly lenient, but not completely since there must be some balance. See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7263&st=&pgnum=96&hilite=) for source (pub. 1674), based on teachings from R. Chaim Vital's output.

Comment: please put links, if possible.

Comment: Consider indicating that some or all of these are rejected and or explained different by the Rishonim.

Comment: @mevaqesh You just did it for me :) I imagined someone asking for sources, doing research, will inevitably see so for themselves. The interpretations and deliberations of these statements are vast; the intention was to point to a few primary sources of the discussions carried throughout the centuries.

Comment: "Mikdash Melech to Zohar Parshas Bereishis 17b. 
In the time of the Messiah, we will follow the law according to Shammai. Hillel represents kindness and Shammai severity (hence the rulings of Beit Hillel are almost always more lenient). When the Messiah comes the advantage of the severity will be revealed and therefore the law will be in accordance with Beit Shammai." - https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/14453

Answer (score 1):

All laws of mourning for the Beit Hamikdash, for example Tisha Be'av as we have it now, tearing kriyah at the Kotel, and breaking a glass at a wedding, won't be relevant anymore.

Comment: I agree, but please provide links. Thanks.